# Testing non-consumable IAP items in Google Play

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm using Google Play IABv3 and want to be able to easily test what I do (not surprisingly). Since IABv3 all items are managed and it's up to the application to consume the items that it considers consumables.

I'm not sure what the expected work flow is with testing non-consumable products. To be able to test the purchase flow more than once you need to be able to remove the previous purchase. However, the purchase is intended to be non-consumable so we obviously don't want to add any code that consumes it (since it could accidentally slip through and remove real users purchases).

I would like some way of clearing a test users account from purchases, which I doubt is possible since there is no "real" test users.

What is the suggested way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use test product IDs instead of real items. Remember to use it only in debug builds.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

> **android.test.purchased**
>
> When you make an In-app Billing request with
>   this product ID, Google Play responds as though you successfully
>   purchased an item. The response includes a JSON string, which contains
>   fake purchase information (for example, a fake order ID). In some
>   cases, the JSON string is signed and the response includes the
>   signature so you can test your signature verification implementation
>   using these responses.
>
> **android.test.canceled**
>
> When you make an In-app
>   Billing request with this product ID Google Play responds as though
>   the purchase was canceled. This can occur when an error is encountered
>   in the order process, such as an invalid credit card, or when you
>   cancel a user's order before it is charged.
>
> **android.test.refunded**
>
> When
>   you make an In-app Billing request with this product ID, Google Play
>   responds as though the purchase was refunded. Refunds cannot be
>   initiated through Google Play's in-app billing service. Refunds must
>   be initiated by you (the merchant). After you process a refund request
>   through your Google Wallet merchant account, a refund message is sent
>   to your application by Google Play. This occurs only when Google Play
>   gets notification from Google Wallet that a refund has been made. For
>   more information about refunds, see Handling IN_APP_NOTIFY messages
>   and In-app Billing Pricing.
>
> **android.test.item_unavailable**
>
> When you make an In-app Billing request with this product ID, Google Play
>   responds as though the item being purchased was not listed in your
>   application's product list.

Comment: This doesn't work since the "android.test.purchased" is treated like a managed product, which means you need to consume before testing again. Sure, you could add an if-statement to consume it directly upon purchasing but that would create lots of different unwanted side effects.

Comment: @alaeus so the best solution is to add code for consuming the items only in debug build and test your app on real product ids. You can create multiple different implementations of a class depending on a build type/flavor. The one in debug build will consume items, but the release version will do nothing when its methods are called.

Comment: That seems very error prone since it's either only usable by devs or having the testers not using the release build. Another solution would be to make a separate non-published application (using the same id) which is used to consume all your purchases. That feels overkill though.